# Is a antisymmetric matrix $\otimes$ a general matrix still antisymmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an Antisymmetric Matrix $A$ and a general square matrix $G$, is the Kronecker product of these two matrices antisymmetric again:

$$ A \otimes G =? $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $(A \otimes B)^t = A^t \otimes B^t$, if $A$ is antisymmetric, we have 
$$ (A \otimes B)^t = A^t \otimes B^t = -A \otimes B^t $$
which is in general $\ne -A \otimes B$. But: If $A$ is antisymmetric and $B$ is symmetric, then
$$ (A \otimes B)^t = A^t \otimes B^t = -A \otimes B^t = -A\otimes B $$